# i want to know how to get page url to open a menu in my sidenav bar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

this is my navbar what i want to do is write javascript or jQuery to get the current pages url and open the corresponding dropdown container i want to open the part of the side nav depending on the url i have this javascript written but it doesnt work

```
 $(function() {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("home") > -1)
      $('.dropdown-toggle.home').dropdown('toggle');
    else if (window.location.href.indexOf("FRAMEWORKS") > -1)
      $('.dropdown-toggle.FRAMEWORKS').dropdown('toggle');
    else if (window.location.href.indexOf("Strategize phase") > -1)
      $('.dropdown-toggle.Strategize phase').dropdown('toggle');
    else if (window.location.href.indexOf("Standardize phase") > -1)
      $('.dropdown-toggle.Standardize phase').dropdown('toggle');
    else if (window.location.href.indexOf("Implement phase") > -1)
      $('.dropdown-toggle.Implement phase').dropdown('toggle');
    else if (window.location.href.indexOf("Integrate phase") > -1)
      $('.dropdown-toggle.Integrate phase').dropdown('toggle');
    else (window.location.href.indexOf("About") > -1)
      $('.dropdown-toggle.ABOUT').dropdown('toggle');
  });
```

Home

```
      <button id class="dropdown-btn FRAMEWORKS" href="#">FRAMEWORKS    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>


    <div class="dropdown-container">
      <div class="sub">
      <a href="#">Framework</a>

      <button class="dropdown-btn" href="#">Strategize phase<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <div class="subSub">
        <a href="#">Enterprise Innovation Audit Canvas</a>
        <a href="#">Pre-Audit Business Definition Questions</a>
        <button class="dropdown-btn" href="#">Tools and Canvases for the Enterprise Innovation Capability Audit<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
          <div class="dropdown-container">
            <div class="subSubSub">
          <a href="#">Enterprise Innovation Maturity Canvas</a>
          <a href="#">Enterprise Innovation Maturity Evaluation Grid Canvas</a>
          <a href="#">Enterprise Innovation Maturity Road map Canvas</a>
        </div>
      </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="dropdown-btn" href="#">Standardize Phaze<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <div class="subSub">
              <button class="dropdown-btn" href="#">Innovation Culture Fostering Approach<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                <div class="dropdown-container">
                  <div class="subSubSub">
                      <a href="#">Innovation Fostering Approach Summary</a>
                      <a href="#">4I- Inspire, Ideate, Implement and Impact Enterprise Innovation Fostering Model</a>
                      <a href="#">Enterprise Team Inventiveness Persona</a>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, as this isn't a code writing service, I would recommend checking out [mcve] to learn how to best ask your question.

Comment: sorry man im new to here ad couldnt add the snippet of the code i used dont take it personal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure, what you want to achieve with your question but here is a small code snippet related to your question based on [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/):

https://jsfiddle.net/vrjx2hde/4/

If you want to learn it, try [this Link](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_dropdown.asp).

If you will use it in your environment, you have to be sure, that your URL contains a word, which you can find with:

```
window.location.href.indexOf(...)
```

e.g.: http://localhost/FRAMEWORKS.html

In this case your 'Frameworks' dropdown will open after your document is loaded.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  if (window.location.href.indexOf("FRAMEWORKS") > -1){
     $('#my-id-FRAMEWORKS').dropdown("toggle");
  }
 });
```